# How to return the next record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my Rails app I have a function `next` which I am using in my `show` templates to link to the next `product` (ordered by `price`):

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base 

  belongs_to  :user

  def next
    Product.where("user_id = ? AND price > ?", user_id, price).order("price ASC").first 
  end

end
```

The problem is that this function works only when all products have *different* prices. The moment there are multiple products with the *same* price, the `next` function picks one product randomly (?) thereby skipping all the others.

Is there a way to make this function return the next product, even though it has the same price? (if the price is the same, the products could be ordered simply by ID or date)

I tried replacing `>` with `>=` but that didn't work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you can try this `self.class.first(:conditions => ['id > ?', self.id], :limit => 1, :offset => 0, :order => "id ASC")`

Comment: By next record do you mean the product whose cost is higher than this one but is the first in that group ?? Ex : P1-10,P2-12,P3-9,P4-11..next for P1 is P4 is it ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `id` in `where` clause and in `order` as well

```
  def next
    Product.where("user_id = ? AND price >= ? AND id > ?", user_id, price, id).order("total, id").first 
  end
```

Comment: I think you forgot `, id`. No? Anyway, this doesn't work because it will ignore products that have a higher `price` **but** a lower `id`.